# How do I create a 1 by 1 matrix in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, opencv-mat

The following piece of code doesn't seem to work.

```
T = A*(B_new.t())*(A.t()) + x_bar;
```

Matrix A is of dimension 1 by 2, Matrix B_new.t() is of dimension 2 by 1,  x_bar is a double variable of dimension 1 by 1. The dimension of T has to be dimension 1 by 1.

```
cv::Matx12d A = cv::Matx12d(1,0);

cv::Matx21d B_new = F_x* A_p *F_x.t() + K_x* L_x* K_x.t();

double x_bar = 100;
```

After running the code, I received a message:

```
no operator "+" matches these operands
operand types are: cv::Matx<double, 1, 1> + double
```

How to make changes to the error?

Comment: From the error message it looks like `x_bar` is of type `double`. It needs to be of type `cv::Matx<double, 1, 1>`?

Comment: I can't create a 1 by 1 matrix for x_bar. That's the problem.

Comment: Can you add to your question how you declared `A`, `B_new`, and `x_bar`?

Comment: cv::Matx12d A = cv::Matx12d(1,0);

cv::Matx21d B = F_x* A_p *F_x.t() + K_x* L_x* K_x.t();

double x_bar = 100;

Comment: Well, how about `cv::Matx<double, 1, 1> b = {100}`? Something like that?

Comment: is addition of scalars properly defined mathematically? *multiplication* has obvious semantics but addition...? in the programming sense, sure. Try adding a `cv::Scalar()` and see if that does it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether this should have worked. C++ *could* have inserted a Scalar() constructor but didn't. I'd definitely expect it to work if you use `cv::Scalar` instead of the plain value. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/question-on-matrix-multiplication-to-get-a-1-by-1-matrix-in-opencv/8290